# Why is the inherited function inaccessible?

Tags: c++, inheritance

A small example to reproduce the error in Visual Studio (Community) 2022:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void b();
protected:
    std::string Method() {
        return "Base::Method";
    }
};

class SubA : public Base {
public:
    // Prevent compiler from optimizing class away.
    int doSomething() {
        return 7;
    }
};


int main() {
    SubA sa;
    sa.doSomething();
    sa.Method(); // <-- Function is inaccessible.
}
```

Why is the error? The inheritance is public and I'm calling `Method` on an object from the `SubA` class.

Comment: it's `protected`, not `public`, which means it's accessible by the derived classes, but not the client code

Comment: Because you've declared this method as `protected:` in base class it means you can use it inside SibA or another inherited classes but not as a public API.

Comment: The accessibility of the method is the *minimum* between what it was declared as and what your inheritance is (ex: declared public but private inheritance -> its private). in your case you declared protected and public inherited -> its protected.

Comment: p.s. you can "promote" accessibility to another level with `using` directive. E.g. `using Base:: Method` under `public:` section of `SubA` will make `Method` member function public

Comment: "*The inheritance is public*" - Using public inheritance does not make protected members be public to outside code.

Answer (score 2):

> The inheritance is public

But the member function is protected. You're accessing the member function from `main` which is outside of the scope of the class or its decendants, so it has no access to protected member functions.